# Match against query not working properly in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I have problem with match against query, code is given below.

```
    select
    `b`.`name` as `resNm`,
    `s`.`name` as `suburbs`,
    `b`.`city`
from
    `businesses` as `b`
left join `suburbs` as `s`
    on `s`.`id` = `s`.`id`
where
    (
        MATCH (`b`.`suburb`, `b`.`city`, `s`.`name`) AGAINST ('road number 12' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    ) and
    MATCH (delivery_areas, `s`.`name`) AGAINST ('road number 12' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND 
    `is_bolo` = 1
group by
    `s`.`name`
order by
    `s`.`level` desc,
    `s`.`name` asc
```

And getting all record form database

My original query is below.

```
select
    `b`.`name` as `resNm`,
    `s`.`name` as `suburbs`,
    `b`.`city`
from
    `businesses` as `b`
left join `suburbs` as `s`
    on `s`.`id` = `s`.`id`
where
    (
        `b`.`suburb` like '%road number 12%' or
        `b`.`city` like '%road number 12%' or
        `s`.`name` like '%road number 12%'
    ) and
    `delivery_areas` like '%road number 12%' and
    `is_bolo` = 1 and
    `s`.`name` like '%road number 12%'
group by
    `s`.`name`
order by
    `s`.`level` desc,
    `s`.`name` asc
```

I like to get record like following.

If user search `road no 12` then get records like suburb,name,city,delivery areas contains record like 'road' or like 'number' or like '12' or like 'road no' etc.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how is php and laravel remotely related and full-text not a tag here

Comment: the bottom half makes no sense

Comment: `on s.id = s.id` <-- ?

Comment: @DavidBarker that is use for self joining. that query is made by laravel4.2 ignore that. I need to convert second query in MATCH AGAINST query